# htaccess rewrite url remove dynamic & static subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to remove dynamic & static folder name from url using htaccess

> example.com/theme/dynamicfolder/

to

> example.com/

**theme** is static directory &
**dynamicfolder** is value from mysql database

my current htaccess script

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# external redirect to redirect old URL to pretty URL    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /a\.php\?slug=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1? [R=301,L,NE]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sitemap\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /sitemap.xml [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /contact\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /contact [R=301,L,NE]


# internal rewrite to forward to actual URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^article/([\w-]+)/?$ a.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of current [**`.htaccess`**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file in the root directory.

Add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^staticFolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ staticFolder/anotherFolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

So the url:

**https://yourdomain.tld/staticFolder/anotherFolder/any0therValue**

Can be accessed from:

**https://yourdomain.tld/any0therValue**

But in that case, the *anotherFolder* should be predefined.

Comment: thanks for response, but not working - RewriteRule ^theme/([^\/]+)/(.*)$ $2 [L,QSA]

Comment: Is [rewrite module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled in apache? because it was [tested](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Comment: yes enabled. kindly check above existing htaccess script

Comment: kindly check the update

Comment: internal server error